# How to find maximum and minimum process boundaries while debugging?

Tags: gdb, dynamic-analysis

If I'm using GDB or any other debugger, I just want to know where the respective images are loaded for a given process.

Say I create an executable HelloWorld, and it just prints hello.

It has a maximum and minimum bounds in memory.

I am asking this question because I'm looking for certain bytes in memory; I'm going to call gdb's find with these values as parameter.

Thanks in advance, I apologize if it seems novice, but I've not read the entire GDB manual.

Comment: If  you're using gdb, you're probably on linux. In this case, you can check /proc/<pid>/maps for information which address space is mapped to the process.

Comment: Ok, this answers my question, but I still haven't solved my problem. Thank you, I will post a new question with my actual problem.

Comment: Here: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8027/how-to-find-location-of-environment-variables-in-64-bit-binaries-at-runtime